# How to create UIImage with vertical gradient using "from-color" and "to-color"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

How to create new image just with gradient colors, using "from-color" and "to-color"?

Comment: Why create an image when you could just make a gradient?

Comment: You can create a UIView, add a CAGradientLayer with the colors you want to it, and then render the view to a UIImage. If there is something of this you want me to deploy to a larger explanation, tell me and I will post an answer with the code.
Good luck!

Comment: I suspect you know answer. Would you like say us?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A simpler answer, using a [CAGradientLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/).

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
layer.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor,  // start color
                 (__bridge id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor]; // end color

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
@try {
  [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
} @finally {
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Answer (score 25):

First you need to create a graphics context in the required size:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Create a colour space:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
```

Now create the gradient:

```
size_t gradientNumberOfLocations = 2;
CGFloat gradientLocations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
CGFloat gradientComponents[8] = { r0, g0, b0, a0,     // Start color
                                  r1, g1, b1, a1, };  // End color

CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (colorspace, gradientComponents, gradientLocations, gradientNumberOfLocations);
```

Fill the context with the gradient - this assumes a vertical gradient:

```
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0, 0), CGPointMake(0, size.height), 0);
```

Now you can create an image from the context:

```
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Finally release the gradient, colour space and context:

```
CGGradientRelease(gradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: if a0 + a1 = 2 (no transparency in either color) then you can probably make the image opaque.

Comment: Thanks, excellent answer :) Just changed second point y value from 0 to size.height.

Answer (score 21):

I think, It's more swifty

Swift 3

```
struct GradientPoint {
   var location: CGFloat
   var color: UIColor
}



extension UIImage {
convenience init?(size: CGSize, gradientPoints: [GradientPoint]) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }       // If the size is zero, the context will be nil.
    guard let gradient = CGGradient(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colorComponents: gradientPoints.flatMap { $0.color.cgColor.components }.flatMap { $0 }, locations: gradientPoints.map { $0.location }, count: gradientPoints.count) else {
        return nil
    }

    context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: CGPoint.zero, end: CGPoint(x: 0, y: size.height), options: CGGradientDrawingOptions())
    guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()?.cgImage else { return nil }
    self.init(cgImage: image)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
}
}


extension UIImageView {
   func gradated(gradientPoints: [GradientPoint]) {
    let gradientMaskLayer       = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientMaskLayer.frame     = frame
    gradientMaskLayer.colors    = gradientPoints.map { $0.color.cgColor }
    gradientMaskLayer.locations = gradientPoints.map { $0.location as NSNumber }
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientMaskLayer, at: 0)
}
}
```

Use like this,

```
let points = [GradientPoint(location: 0, color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 0.2530534771)), GradientPoint(location: 0.2, color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9686274529, green: 0.78039217, blue: 0.3450980484, alpha: 0.5028884243)), GradientPoint(location: 0.4, color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.721568644, green: 0.8862745166, blue: 0.5921568871, alpha: 0.3388534331)),
          GradientPoint(location: 0.6, color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.2588235438, green: 0.7568627596, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 0.3458681778)), GradientPoint(location: 0.8, color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 0.3851232394))]

UIImage(size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300), gradientPoints: points)


let veniceImageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "venice-italy.jpg"))
veniceImageView.gradated(gradientPoints: points)
```

I tested on swift 3.
Check the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATED TO Swift 3**

I wrote `UIImage` extension for Swift but you can also use it from Objective-C:

```
import UIKit

private let ChannelDivider: CGFloat = 255

public class RGBA: NSObject {
    var red: CGFloat
    var green: CGFloat
    var blue: CGFloat
    var alpha: CGFloat

    init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        self.red = red
        self.green = green
        self.blue = blue
        self.alpha = alpha
    }

    init(intRed: Int, green: Int, blue: Int, alpha: Int) {
        self.red = CGFloat(intRed)/ChannelDivider
        self.green = CGFloat(green)/ChannelDivider
        self.blue = CGFloat(blue)/ChannelDivider
        self.alpha = CGFloat(alpha)/ChannelDivider
    }
}

public class Grayscale: NSObject {
    var white: CGFloat
    var alpha: CGFloat

    init(white: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        self.white = white
        self.alpha = alpha
    }
}

public class GradientPoint<C>: NSObject {
    var location: CGFloat
    var color: C

    init(location: CGFloat, color: C) {
        self.location = location
        self.color = color
    }
}

extension UIImage {

    public class func image(withGradientPoints gradientPoints: [GradientPoint<[CGFloat]>], colorSpace: CGColorSpace, size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0);
        guard
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
            let gradient = CGGradient(colorSpace: colorSpace,
                                      colorComponents: gradientPoints.flatMap { $0.color },
                                      locations: gradientPoints.map { $0.location }, count: gradientPoints.count) else {
                                        return nil
        }

        context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: CGPoint.zero, end: CGPoint(x: 0, y: size.height), options: CGGradientDrawingOptions())
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }

    public class func image(withRGBAGradientPoints gradientPoints: [GradientPoint<RGBA>], size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return image(withGradientPoints: gradientPoints.map {
            GradientPoint(location: $0.location, color: [$0.color.red, $0.color.green, $0.color.blue, $0.color.alpha])
        }, colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), size: size)
    }

    public class func image(withRGBAGradientColors gradientColors: [CGFloat: RGBA], size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return image(withRGBAGradientPoints: gradientColors.map {  GradientPoint(location: $0, color: $1)}, size: size)
    }

    public class func image(withGrayscaleGradientPoints gradientPoints: [GradientPoint<Grayscale>], size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return image(withGradientPoints: gradientPoints.map {
            GradientPoint(location: $0.location, color: [$0.color.white, $0.color.alpha]) },
                     colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(), size: size)
    }

    public class func image(withGrayscaleGradientColors gradientColors: [CGFloat: Grayscale], size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return image(withGrayscaleGradientPoints: gradientColors.map { GradientPoint(location: $0, color: $1) }, size: size)
    }
}
```

You can create gradient image using RGBA colors:

```
// Objective-C
RGBA *startColor = [[RGBA alloc] initWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
RGBA *endColor = [[RGBA alloc] initWithIntRed:0 green:255 blue:0 alpha:255];
UIImage *gradientImage = [UIImage imageWithRGBAGradient: @{ @0: startColor, @1: endColor} size: CGSizeMake(32, 64)];

// Swift
let startColor = RGBA(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
let endColor = RGBA(intRed: 0, green: 255, blue: 0, alpha: 255)
let gradientImage = UIImage.image(withRGBAGradientPoints: [0: startColor, 1: endColor], size: CGSizeMake(32, 64))
```

And grayscale colors:

```
// Objective-C
Grayscale *startColor = [[Grayscale alloc] initWithWhite:1 alpha:1];
Grayscale *endColor = [[Grayscale alloc] initWithWhite:0 alpha: 0.5];
UIImage *gradientImage = [UIImage imageWithGrayscaleGradient: @{ @0: startColor, @1: endColor} size: CGSizeMake(32, 64)];

// Swift
let startColor = Grayscale(white: 1, alpha: 1)
let endColor = Grayscale(white:0, alpha: 0.5)
let gradientImage = UIImage.image(withGrayscaleGradientPoints: [0: startColor, 1: endColor], size: CGSizeMake(32, 64))
```

If you are not going to use this code from Objective-C than you can remove `NSObject` inheritance from `RGBA`, `Grayscale` and `GradientPoint`.

Comment: Had to convert this to Swift 3 to work on my project. I've added an answer below, as it's too big to put in this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version of Mixel's answer

```
import UIKit

private let ChannelDivider: CGFloat = 255

public class RGBA: NSObject {
    var red: CGFloat
    var green: CGFloat
    var blue: CGFloat
    var alpha: CGFloat

    init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        self.red = red
        self.green = green
        self.blue = blue
        self.alpha = alpha
    }

    init(intRed: Int, green: Int, blue: Int, alpha: Int) {
        self.red = CGFloat(intRed)/ChannelDivider
        self.green = CGFloat(green)/ChannelDivider
        self.blue = CGFloat(blue)/ChannelDivider
        self.alpha = CGFloat(alpha)/ChannelDivider
    }
}

public class Grayscale: NSObject {
    var white: CGFloat
    var alpha: CGFloat

    init(white: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        self.white = white
        self.alpha = alpha
    }
}

public class GradientPoint<C>: NSObject {
    var location: CGFloat
    var color: C

    init(location: CGFloat, color: C) {
        self.location = location
        self.color = color
    }
}

extension UIImage {

    public class func image(withGradientPoints gradientPoints: [GradientPoint<[CGFloat]>], colorSpace: CGColorSpace, size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0);
        guard
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
            let gradient = CGGradient(colorSpace: colorSpace,
                                  colorComponents: gradientPoints.flatMap { $0.color },
                                  locations: gradientPoints.map { $0.location }, count: gradientPoints.count) else {
                                    return nil
        }

        context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: CGPoint.zero, end: CGPoint(x: 0, y: size.height), options: CGGradientDrawingOptions())
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }

    public class func image(withRGBAGradientPoints gradientPoints: [GradientPoint<RGBA>], size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return image(withGradientPoints: gradientPoints.map {
            GradientPoint(location: $0.location, color: [$0.color.red, $0.color.green, $0.color.blue, $0.color.alpha])
        }, colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), size: size)
    }

    public class func image(withRGBAGradientColors gradientColors: [CGFloat: RGBA], size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return image(withRGBAGradientPoints: gradientColors.map {  GradientPoint(location: $0, color: $1)}, size: size)
    }

    public class func image(withGrayscaleGradientPoints gradientPoints: [GradientPoint<Grayscale>], size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return image(withGradientPoints: gradientPoints.map {
            GradientPoint(location: $0.location, color: [$0.color.white, $0.color.alpha]) },
                                 colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(), size: size)
    }

    public class func image(withGrayscaleGradientColors gradientColors: [CGFloat: Grayscale], size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return image(withGrayscaleGradientPoints: gradientColors.map { GradientPoint(location: $0, color: $1) }, size: size)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need some to add some **TRANSPARENCY** to the gradient?

Set the alpha value in the color's declaration as follows:

```
UIView *countDownView =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-100, self.view.frame.size.height/2- 100, 200,200)];
countDownView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;

UIColor *colorFrom = [UIColor colorWithRed: 130/255. green:59/255. blue:216/255. alpha:1.0];
UIColor *colorTo = [UIColor colorWithRed: 55/255. green:21/255. blue:250/255. alpha:0.5];

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = countDownView.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[colorFrom CGColor], (id)[colorTo CGColor], nil];
gradient.cornerRadius = 20.0; //set the same cornerRadius than the UIView if needed

[countDownView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Need to remove it?

```
[gradient removeFromSuperlayer];//not tested
```

*[works on xCode 7.2.1 for iOS 9]*

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implemented [Simon's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16788775/391605) (elsewhere in this thread) to create a reusable "hot" and "cold" `UIImage` like below:

[image: UIImage for hot and cold]

Objective-C code:

```
-(UIImage*)createHotOrColdImage:(BOOL)bHot
{
    //  Create a UIImage with either a "Hot" or "Cold" gradient background
    //
    const int WIDTH = 75;
    const int HEIGHT = 44;

    //  Do we want our UIImage to fade from black-to-red or black-to-blue ?
    UIColor* color = (bHot) ? [UIColor redColor] : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);


    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    CGFloat red = components[0];
    CGFloat green = components[1];
    CGFloat blue = components[2];

    size_t gradientNumberOfLocations = 4;
    CGFloat gradientLocations[4] = { 0.0, 0.3, 0.7, 1.0 };
    CGFloat gradientComponents[16] = { red, green, blue, 0,
        red, green, blue, 1,
        red, green, blue, 1,
        red, green, blue, 0 }; 

    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (colorspace, gradientComponents, gradientLocations, gradientNumberOfLocations);

    //  Create a UIImage containing this gradient
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //  Make sure the gradient is vertical
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0, 0), CGPointMake(0, HEIGHT), 0);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

To use:

```
UIImage* hotImage = [self createHotOrColdImage:TRUE];
UIImage* coldImage = [self createHotOrColdImage:FALSE];
```

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin solution:

```
    private UIImage GenerateBackgroundGradient(CGSize size, CGColor[] colors)
    {
        UIImage backgroundGradient = null;

        var layer = new CAGradientLayer
        {
            Frame = View.Frame,
            Colors = colors
        };

        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(size);
        layer.RenderInContext(UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext());
        backgroundGradient = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

        return backgroundGradient;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/leszek-s/LSCategories
It allows creating image with gradient like this:

```
UIImage *gradient = [UIImage lsGradientImageWithSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100) startColor:[UIColor redColor] endColor:[UIColor greenColor] startPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) endPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 1.0)];
```