# Get UIImage with gradient fill color using core graphics

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics

I am creating one category for UIImage in which I pass an image and get that imaged mask with filled color which I provided. Now I want to add gradient instead of single color filled. Below is method how I generate masked image with single filled color. How can I add gradient instead of single color?

```
- (UIImage *)imageMaskedWithGradientColor:(UIColor *)maskColor
{
    NSParameterAssert(maskColor != nil);

        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.size.width, self.size.height);
        UIImage *newImage = nil;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageRect.size, NO, self.scale);
        {
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, -(imageRect.size.height));

            CGContextClipToMask(context, imageRect, self.CGImage);
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, maskColor.CGColor);
            CGContextFillRect(context, imageRect);

            newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add gradient mask by below code

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientMask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientMask.frame = self.myImageView.bounds;
gradientMask.colors = @[(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];  // Change colors as you want
self.myImageView.layer.mask = gradientMask;
```

for more information read Apple official doc. for [CAGradientLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cagradientlayer)

Comment: I am generating mask image programmatically. Your solution would not work.

Comment: Means your imageView is programmatically ?

Comment: I mean, I will draw image programmatically. With specific design and apply mask with gradient in it.

Comment: use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788305/how-to-create-uiimage-with-vertical-gradient-using-from-color-and-to-color