# Apply gradient to PDF

Tags: ios, swift, svg, swift4

I plan to convert all my images to PDF, and some images had gradient. Is there any way to apply a gradient to a `UIImageView` that has a PDF image in it?

I know that the PDFs will be converted to PNGs on build time, [and I found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788305/how-to-create-uiimage-with-vertical-gradient-using-from-color-and-to-color/16788775) for applying a gradient on PNG, and was wondering whether it will work for PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **yes and no**. The gradient will show up, but your image might get degraded. Here's why:

If you have a PDF-based asset with the **Preserve vector data** setting disabled, your asset will work in the same way as it did before the gradient was applied.

However, if you have that setting enabled for the asset and you are using [this sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44866438/3151675) for applying the gradient, `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` will rasterize the asset and it will look as if you had **Preserve vector data** unchecked.

---

A possible solution for this would be drawing a gradient in the PDF file itself - of course, you cannot generate a gradient procedurally that way.

Another workaround would be drawing the shape using `CALayer`s and `CGPath`s. A good tool for generating code from vector images is [PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com).