# How to give gradient to SVG image in iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, svg

I am using svg images in iOS project. I have to set gradient to svg image but I have no idea that how I give gradient to svg image in iOS. If anyone has done this earlier then please help me out.

I am using this function to get different color image from svg image in bundle. Now I want to fill gradient color to svg image. How I can achieve this. I am using SVGKit Library for this.

```
func getImageFromSVG_StaticColor(imgStr:String,colorStr:String) -> UIImage {

    let svgURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: imgStr, withExtension: "svg")
    let img_data = try? Data(contentsOf: svgURL!)
    let image : SVGKImage = SVGKImage(data: img_data)
    
    image.fillColor(color: UIColor.init(hexString: colorStr, alpha: 1.0), opacity: 1.0)
    
    return image.uiImage
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create UIImage with vertical gradient using "from-color" and "to-color"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788305/how-to-create-uiimage-with-vertical-gradient-using-from-color-and-to-color)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. We need much more information... Have you added your SVG to as an image in your Assets catalog? Or are you using code to read it and parse it into layers? Does your SVG file have a gradient in it the is not showing?

Answer (score 0):

you should override UIview class on image svg and set gradient color on UIview

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50))
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

gradient.frame = view.bounds
gradient.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]

view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

Comment: How I override UIView class on image svg, can you please elaborate?